# Как сформировать SQL запрос с русскими символами в выражениях?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, django, oracle

Требуется сформировать SQL запрос, где в `WHERE`выражении содержатся русские символы.

```
sap_code = 'ОВОЩИ – ФРУКТЫ'
sql_string = 'SELECT ' \
            'SAP_CODE, ' \
            'SKU, ' \
        'FROM INFO ' \
        f'WHERE ROWNUM < {settings.NQ_SQL_LIMIT}'
if sap_code:
    sql_string += f' AND SAP_CODE = {sap_code}'
with connections[db].cursor() as cursor:
    exec_result = cursor.execute(
        sql_string
    )
```

Но выдает такую ошибку:

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character`

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Каккая у вас кодировка в БД и на клиенте?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Символьные значения надо заключать в одиночные кавычки, в данном случае:

```
AND SAP_CODE = \'{sap_code}\'
```

Но включать значения переменных непосредственно в запрос **ни в коем случае не следует** (см. пояснение ниже). Передавайте их как переменные связывания.
Вот воспроизводимый пример, как надо сделать:

```
from cx_Oracle import connect 

conn = connect ('me/pass@srv/pdb1', encoding="utf-8")
curs = conn.cursor ()
code = 'ОВОЩИ'
rown = 1
text = '''
    select * from (
        select :1 code from dual)
    where rownum <= :2 and code = :1'''
curs.execute (text, (code, rown))
rows = curs.fetchall ()
conn.close ()
print (rows)
```

Результат:

```
[('ОВОЩИ',)]
```

---

> почему не следует включать в запрос значения переменных напрямую?

Пример того, как делать **не надо**:

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM tab WHERE code = '{code}'"
```

По нескольким причинам:

- Чтобы обезопасить себя от [SQL Injections](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
- Чтобы не "засорять" *Library Cache* похожими запросами, отличающимися только значением литерала.
- Запрос вида `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE code = :1` будет парситься (*hard parse*) только первый раз. Это дополнительно сэкономит время на парсинг.